# How can i check "isNumeric()" only if input exists?

Tags: javascript, node.js

So im using express-validator to validate some inputs in my form. As you can see, cuit, telefono, celular and cbu are optional inputs that have "isNumeric()". So i want express-validator to check those inputs only if they exist. I thought that by adding ".optional()" i could solve this problem, but im still getting "invalid value" error when they are empty. How can i solve this? Thank you.

```
proveedores_controllers.set_proveedor_input_rules = [
    body("nombre").isLength({min: 2, max:30}).withMessage("El nombre debe tener entre 2 y 30 caracteres."),
    body("apellido").isLength({min: 2, max:30}).withMessage("El apellido debe tener entre 2 y 30 caracteres."),
    body("cuit").optional().isLength({max:18}).withMessage("El cuit debe tener como maximo 18 digitos").isNumeric(),
    body("direccion").optional().isLength({max:30}).withMessage("La direccion debe tener como maximo 30 caracteres."),
    body("localidad").optional().isLength({max:30}).withMessage("La localidad debe tener como maximo 30 caracteres."),
    body("rubro").optional().isLength({max:30}).withMessage("El rubro debe tener como maximo 30 caracteres."),
    body("telefono").optional().isLength({max:18}).withMessage("El telefono debe tener como maximo 18 digitos.").isNumeric(),
    body("celular").optional().isLength({max:18}).withMessage("El celular debe tener como maximo 18 digitos.").isNumeric(),
    body("email").optional().isLength({max:50}).withMessage("El email debe tener como maximo 50 caracteres.").normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
    body("cbu").optional().isLength({max:18}).withMessage("El cbu debe tener como maximo 18 digitos.").isNumeric(),
]
```

Comment: You may use `.exists()`. Can read it here. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#existsoptions

Comment: Still not working with .exists()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, *if* the fields are actually non-existent in `req.body`. If they exist *but are empty*, they will not be considered by the `optional` filter (which, by default, will only check for *undefined*) and get passed to `isNumeric`, which subsequently fails.

For example, let's consider your rule for `cuit`.

Then this request body would pass validation because `cuit` is undefined:

```
{}
```

This would fail validation, because it is defined but not numerical:

```
{
  "cuit" : ""
}
```

If you want to allow empty strings to pass validation, [you need to use this](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html#optionaloptions):

```
.optional({ checkFalsy : true })
```

But realize that these this will allow false values (`""`, `false`, `null`) to still be present in `req.body`. They will only not be checked to see if they are numerical.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below format to validate input

```js
const { check } = require("express-validator");

  check("age")
    .exists()
    .isNumeric()
    .withMessage("please enter valid age")
```